# Local Push Notification iOS

Tags: javascript, react, ios, react-native, xcode

Estou usando a lib [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) para agendar notificações em um app,e estou com um problema para criar uma notificação local que se repita em determinado intervalo para iOS, ou seja, a cada 2, 3 ou 4 dias.

Para Android estou conseguindo criar, mas o mesmo não funciona para iOS. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma alternativa para desenvolver isso para iOS.

Código que funciona no Android:

```html
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      title: name,
      message: message,
      date: new Date(),
      repeatType: 'time', // (Apenas Android)
      repeatTime: moment.duration(2, 'days').asMilliseconds() // (Apenas Android) Repete a cada 2 dias
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta curta:**

*Precisa usar algum recurso fora da lib usada. Não consegui encontrar uma maneira de usar apenas a lib.*

**Resposta longa (acumulada):**

Uma possibilidade é usar outro lib [1], mas essa solução tem opções muito limitadas: o intervalo deve ser configurado com uma opção 'String' com poucas opções fornecidas.

O melhor será usar a lib que você tem, mas conecte o horário de início ao relógio externo como [2] ou [3].

O método [2] usa uma solução de objeto C para dar o tempo para exibir a mensagem, o método [3] tem uma lib externa para fazer o mesmo.

As partes importantes da solução [3] que considero mais úteis das três opções:

```
import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';

// ao iniciar o programa inicia as notificações
PushNotification.configure(....);

// definindo o tempo a execução.
BackgroundFetch.configure(
  {
    minimumFetchInterval: 15, // minutos para esperar cada ciclo
  },
  async taskId => {
      ....
      PushNotification.localNotification({
            title: 'Título',
            message: `Mensagem longa.`,
            playSound: true,
            soundName: 'default',
          });
    
        // parar a execução.
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
```

Com esse método você pode definir qualquer intervalo para a notificação.

[1] https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155782/configure-repeatinterval-for-local-notifications-in-ios-in-react-native

[3] https://medium.com/@alihaghani/background-tasks-and-local-push-notifications-with-react-native-d63fc7fff9b

**correção:**

Você pode usar esta [lib](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) para definir horários para os eventos e enviar a notificação local como acima.

Isso deve fazer chamadas repetíveis no IOS e Android:

```
BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
    // notificação local
}, 
timeMillis); // calcule aqui o tempo em milissegundos
```

(um dia: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86400000 msec)

**Mais uma opção:**

Você pode disparar o evento com a configuração "todos os dias" e ter uma variável salva na memória local do telefone que informa há quantos dias você enviou a última notificação. Dessa forma, pode ser a cada 2 ou 3 dias. Qualquer quantidade de dias, na verdade.

Uso de "localstorage" em react native (em `index.js`):

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import SyncStorage from 'sync-storage';

...
// inicializar
SyncStorage.set('quantidadeDias', 0);
...

const QUANTIDADE_DIAS_NECESSARIA = 1; // ou 2,3,4...

class NotificationHandler {
  onNotification(notification) {
    
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const diaAgora = SyncStorage.get('quantidadeDias') + 1;
    if (diaAgora == QUANTIDADE_DIAS_NECESSARIA) {
      SyncStorage.set('quantidadeDias', 0);
      // padrão
      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    } else {
      SyncStorage.set('quantidadeDias', diaAgora);
      // não toque na notificação
    }
  }
}
```

A sintaxe do código em NotificationHandler mudou ao longo do tempo, consulte [4] e [5].

**Recursos:**

[4] https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/701

[5] https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1453

Comment: Após a notificação ser disparada, ela é mostrada independente de chamar notification.finish ou não

Comment: e solução de BackgroundTimer também não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma versão separada para o `iOS`

Para você conseguir utiliza-la de acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios)

Você precisa utilizar esse `pacote`:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/push-notification-ios
```

Assim, envés de utilizar `PushNotification`, vocẽ irá utilizar: `PushNotificationIOS`

Para saber como trabalhar melhor com `PushNotificationIOS`, [acesse a documentação oficial deles no github](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios)

O código ficaria assim:

```js
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
      title: name,
      message: message,
      date: new Date(),
      repeatInterval: new Date(Date.now() + 172800 * 1000) // isso faz ele ter um tempo de repetição de dois em dois dias, cada dia tem 86400 segundos, dois dias tem 172800, mude esse valor para a quantidade de dias que você precisaria
    });
```

**(OBS: para `iOS`, envés de `localNotificationSchedule`, é `scheduleLocalNotification`)**

[Link especifíco sobre o `scheduleLocalNotification()` para `iOS`](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios#schedulelocalnotification)

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas não existe as propriedades repeatType e repeatTime nessa lib do iOS. A propriedade de repetição que a doc especifica é essa apenas: repeatInterval?: 'minute' | 'hour' | 'day' | 'week' | 'month' | 'year';

Comment: quando você coloca ` repeatInterval: 'day'`, o que acontece?

Comment: repete uma vez a cada dia (24 horas), o problema é repetir a cada 2, 3, 4 dias

Comment: Ok, vou ver isso agora!

Comment: Dei uma estudada melhor sobre o assunto e consegui chegar nesse resultado, funcionou?

editei a resposta colocando ele.

Comment: Deu esse erro: repeatInterval  should be one of: ( day, hour, minute, month, week, year )"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113436/discussion-between-vynstus-and-codigo-de-senior).

Answer (score -3):

Existe uma versão separada para o iOS

Para você conseguir utiliza-la de acordo com a documentação oficial

Você precisa utilizar esse pacote:

yarn add @react-native-community/push-notification-ios
Assim, envés de utilizar PushNotification, vocẽ irá utilizar: PushNotificationIOS

Para saber como trabalhar melhor com PushNotificationIOS, acesse a documentação oficial deles no github

Comment: Sim, mas a lib do iOS tem limitações para repetir a notificação por determinado intervalo de tempo, que é o caso dessa pergunta, se há alguma alternativa para implementar essa repetição por intervalo

Comment: posso entender o porque ficar dando vote negativo para tudo que nao funciona pra voce ? é só deixa sem voto e dar vote up no que da certo

Comment: Sua resposta parece ser uma cópia de uma das respostas já apresentadas à essa pergunta. Acredito que deve ser por isso que lhe deram down vote. Não vou lhe dar, mas estou esclarecendo o que pode ser. Abraços!